# Unterschied einmal "in der"/"pro" Woche

Tags: meaning, difference, meaning-in-context

Gibt's einen Unterschied zwischen diesen Sätzen oder sind sie austauschbar?

> Einmal in der Woche
>
> Einmal pro Woche

Comment: Ein etwas weit hergeholtes Beispiel: Reden wir von einem langen Zeitraum, z.B. 52 Wochen, und vielen Ereignissen, z.B. 52, dann könnte "einmal pro Woche" auch in dem Zeitraum "geballt auftretende" Ereignisse, wo tatsächlich in einer Woche z.B. 7 Ereignisse aufgetreten sind, und in anderen Wochen dafür gar nicht, bezeichnen. "Einmal in der Woche" läßt so eine Ausnahme nicht zu.

Comment: Die Beispiele sind keine "Sätze". Somit ist die Frage mindestens unklar.

Comment: ... denn in den genannten Grenzfällen hängt die Antwort vom Kontext ab.

Comment: @tofro halte ich dann für falsch; denn es müsste dann "pro *einer* Woche" heissen ... genau einer Woche aus dem 52 eben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Bedeutung ist nahezu identisch. @tofro und @ShegitBrahm haben bereits erklärt, dass es einen Unterschied geben kann:

- *einmal in der Woche*: Etwas erfolgt (fast) ausnahmslos jede Woche.
  Beispiel: *"Ich gehe einmal in der Woche ins Fitnessstudio, jeden Mittwoch."*
- *einmal pro Woche* kann bedeuten, dass etwas im statistischen Mittel einmal pro Woche erfolgt.
  Beispiel: *"Ich gehe einmal pro Woche ins Fitnessstudio, im Winter häufiger, im Sommer weniger oft."*

Answer (score 3):

Die Bedeutung ist die selbe. Allerdings ist die Formulierung "einmal pro Woche" formeller.
"einmal in der Woche" wirkt für mich vom sprachlichen Niveau her etwas einfacher. Ich halte es daher für eher Umgangssprache.

Answer (score 3):

Nein, kein Unterschied.

Naja, vielleicht ein kleiner (persönlicher Eindruck):

- "ich gehe dreimal in der Woche ins Fitnessstudio"
- "dort sind drei Unfälle pro Woche"

D.h., scheinbar ist "ich tue etwas in wiederkehrender Zeiteinheit" mehr für "xmal in der Zeit" während "etwas geschieht in wiederkehrender Zeiteinheit" mehr für "xmal pro Zeit prädestiniert scheint.

Ich verwende auch

- "dreimal die Woche"

Ist m.E. jedoch dem spontanen Sprachgefühl überlassen, denn es gibt keinen Bedeutungsunterschied und alle Beispiele oben brauchen ein Verb, das "Tun" dient also nicht als Unterscheidung.